# Help with this nonlinear PDE please!

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimal-control

I need help solving the following nonlinear PDE. I've been struggling for days!

$$
\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial^2 x}\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} = c\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\right)^2
$$

for $(x,t)\in [0,\infty)\times [0,T)$, with boundary condition

$$
V(T,x)=(x-H)^2
$$
for some known $H$ and $c$.

Comment: What are some of the things you've tried over the past few days?

Comment: Hi John, I've tried separation of variables but it failed, mainly due to the nonlinearity. I also tried a couple of transformations and they all failed.

Comment: Cool.  I think you'll get some more activity on your question if you edit it to include those things.  Maybe even detail which transformations, how you tried to separate the variables, etc.  (You'll also probabily get more upvotes on your question!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help. Let's try separation of variables. Doing so, we let $V(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$. Then the PDE becomes

$$X''(x)T(t)X(x)T'(t) = cX'(x)^2T(t)^2.$$

Isolating $x$ and $t$ gives

$$ \frac{1}{X'(x)^2}X''(x)X(x) = c\frac{T(t)}{T'(t)}$$

Note that

$$\frac{T(t)}{T'(t)} = \frac{c}{(\log T(t))'}$$

and we can also gather terms on the left to get

$$\frac{X''(x)}{X'(x)}\frac{X(x)}{X'(x)} = (\log X'(x))'\frac{1}{(\log X(x))'}.$$

Since each side is a function of a different variable, we see that each side is constant. Thus

$$\frac{(\log X'(x))'}{(\log X(x))'} = D = \frac{c}{(\log T(t))'}$$

Thus,

$$(\log X'(x))' = D(\log X(x))' \Rightarrow \log X'(x) = D\log X(x) + E.$$

Do something similar with $T$.

This trick of noticing that $\frac{y'}{y} = (\log y)'$ is *very* useful when solving ODEs and PDEs as this problem no doubt shows!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: By the way, how do I deal with the boundary condition now? I have more constants to solve for than equations

Comment: The boundary condition actually encodes all of the parameters. You just have to be a little bit clever about how you collect things.